# Вывод одного слова из списка в случайном порядке без повторений

Tags: python, discord-api

Есть заготовленный список слов, нужно что бы рандомно выбиралось слово, отправлялось и больше не использовалось до того момента пока не кончатся все слова.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random                                                                   

l = list(range(10))                                                             
while l:                                                                        
    print(l.pop(random.randrange(len(l))))
```

Вывод:

```
6
8
4
9
5
0
7
2
3
1
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j4i0o3
Слова повторяются
(варианта слов - 3, попыток 5)

Comment: Ну так удалите повторы: `l = list(set(l))`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j4ibio
6 попыток, 3 слова.
Сделал как вы сказали и ничего не изменилось